# All pairs of complex numbers (z,w) satisfying $zw=-1$

Tags: complex-numbers

How would you find all pairs $(z,w)$ that satisfy $zw=-1$

Im stuck on this problem and the best way I can think of would be to guess and check?

Comment: Are you asking for $z,w$ which satisfy both equations, or are there two different questions?

Comment: 2 different equations

Comment: If the equations have nothing to do with each other (i.e. they are separate) then it is better to ask in separate posts.

Comment: $zw=-1$ implies $z=-1/w$ isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $z\ne 0$ and $w = \frac {-1}z$ will do it.  The question is what format do you want?

If you want it is $z = a+bi$ and $w= c+di$ where $c$ and $d$ are expressed in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Then $\frac {-1}{a+bi} = \frac {-1(a-bi)}{(a+bi)(a-bi)} = \frac {-a+bi}{a^2 + b^2} = -\frac {a}{a^2 + b^2} + \frac {b}{a^2 + b^2} i$.

But $z = a+bi$ is not the only way to express complex numbers.

$w = \frac {-1}z$ is a *perfectly* acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

For $zw=-1$ it is the multiplicative inverse in the complex field but with a minus sign:

$w=-\frac{\bar{z}}{z\bar{z}}=$ and $z=-\frac{\bar{w}}{w\bar{w}}=$ for $w,z\neq0$